# How can I mark all emails as 'Read' after IOS Update 5.0 on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, ios

I just updated to iOS 5.0 on my iphone and when it started up for the first time, all of my emails in a POP account are now showing as unread. The total is 79 emails and I don't want to go one at a time marking each one as read. Is there a way to do it in one sweeping motion?

Answer (score 3):

1. Press the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button in the top-right corner.
2. Select all of the emails you want to mark as "read".
3. Press the <kbd>Mark</kbd> button in the bottom-right corner.
4. Choose <kbd>Mark as Read</kbd>

Comment: This works but I was hoping to find a solution that didn't make me have to 'select all of the emails you want to mark as 'read'' one by one. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: It won't take long to select 79 emails... I think this is the best answer you're going to get.

Comment: I have 800+ emails. Is there an easier way to do this for a lot of messages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid ughoavgfhw gave you the answer. It's a "feature" in iOS 5.

But if you work with GMail, it's easy. Go to your browser, check them all and set them on read. If you've enabled push on your iPhone, the mails will be marked as read on your iPhone as well!

Check out this link for a better option.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmaqzeXfO5s

Comment: Like the OP said, it's a POP account, so no IMAP sync and no push.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I didn't read the POP section.